# Three JS SVG Renderer with grid and transparent surfaces

Tags: svg, three.js, render, transparency

I am trying to render SVG Files with threeJS. As PNG files don't look pretty nice I am using now the SVGRenderer.

My SVG Files looks sth like this:

[image: original]

When I render the Image it appears to be completely black (the colour I have chosen though)

[image: rendered by threeJS]

I found the option to render it as a wireframe, but that shows some framelines I don't want to see

[image: rendered by threeJS with wireframe]

My JS looks like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.SVGLoader();
loader.load( 'media/qpartdark/SVG/qpart2.svg', function ( paths ) {
    var group = new THREE.Group();
    group.scale.multiplyScalar( 0.25 );
    group.position.x = - 70;
    group.position.y = 0;
    group.position.z = 0;
    group.scale.y *= -1;
    for ( var i = 0; i < paths.length; i ++ ) {
        var path = paths[ i ];
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
            color: path.color,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            depthWrite: false,
            wireframe: false,
            wireframeLinewidth: 0.01
        } );
        var shapes = path.toShapes( true );
        for ( var j = 0; j < shapes.length; j ++ ) {
            var shape = shapes[ j ];
            var geometry = new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry( shape );
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            group.add( mesh );
        }
    }
    scene.add( group );
} );

//
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true, antialias: true } );
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

Do you have any hints how I can render the svg as in the example?

here is the original SVG: 
[image: original SVG File]

Comment: It seems that the SVG file is not properly supported by `SVGLoader` right now. You might create an issue at github in order to report the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem, I'm tryin to load a svg file, similar than in the question, build with lines, but it's showing a black shape. I have tried to load in the editor, but it get me the same, a block shape. Thanks @Mugen87